# How to build Vue to be served by Python?

Tags: python, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I started a project in Vue 3 (Vite) with the name `poc_test` and chose everything `No`

```
npm init vue@latest

✔ Project name: poc_test
✔ Add TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … No / Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add Cypress for both Unit and End-to-End testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? … No / Yes
✔ Add Prettier for code formatting? … No / Yes
```

I executed the commands to install and then build:

```
cd poc_test
npm install
npm run build
cd dist
```

And finally, I wanted a simple web server to serve the `poc_test` project, so I executed the command.

```
python -m http.server
```

But this error appears in `http://localhost:8000/`:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

How could I build a Vue 3 project that generates only HTML, JS, and CSS files to be served by `python -m http.server`?

If I use `npm install -g http-server` and inside dist `http-server -p 8000` it works, but it doesn't work with `python -m http.server`

**vite.config.js**
this is the configuration file I am using

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with the mimetypes db on your system. You could try this gist: https://gist.github.com/HaiyangXu/ec88cbdce3cdbac7b8d5

Comment: Worked perfectly, the issue was with the lack of configuration in Python, thanks a lot